# How to efficiently create a list of minimum N sized partitions?

Tags: java, list

Creating N partitions for a list where list.size() % N = 0 is easy enough, but is there a way to do this concisely for when this condition isn't met?

```
    Map<Integer, List<InputRecord>> groupedRecords = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numGroups; i++) {
        groupedRecords.put(i, inputRecords.subList(i * N, (i * N) + N));
    }
```

The above kind of works but if the list doesn't divide into N you can have a list of < N size remaining, which doesn't meet the condition of N sized partitions.

The only solution I can think up is to randomly select partition sizes > N and < N + random(10), and then 'peek' at what's left after, and if the size is less than N, to include that in the partition, but that doesn't seem clean. Is there a better way?

Constraints: list.size() > N >= 3

Comment: the question is unclear. the minimum N = {1 if list.size() > 0, 0 if list.size() = 0} always for `list.size() % 1 always = 0`; if you want minimum partition, N should be list.size() where `list.size() % list.size() always = 0 (list.size() != 0 here)`

Comment: Ah yeah, should add another constraint, that list.size() > N >= 3

Comment: another problem is how to deal with list.size() is prime number? then under the constraint, there is no solution. and for N, why not do `numGroups = -1; for (i = 3; i < list.size(); i ++) if (list.size() % i === 0) numGroups = i;`? if `numGroups` get -1, no solution; otherwise use the `numGroups` to divide your list ...